# Create PHP safe string and get back 1st string from converted string

Tags: php

I have text box when user enter value and submit form i store that string inside PHP file

As example

user enter value: `c/om'n" tec\t`

now i want to store user submit vale in php file
so i get user enter string and write in php file as bellow

```
define ( 'TEXT_VAL', 'c/om'n" tec\t' );
```

this php code gave to me syntax error
i want to convert user enter value to safe php string something look bellow

```
define ( 'TEXT_VAL', 'c/om\'n\" tec\t' );
```

After that how to get 1st user enter value(`c/om'n" tec\t`) form TEXT_VAL variable

i try using addslashes() and stripslashes() php functions but when user enter `\` i fail to get user enter value form the converted string

My Questions:

1. How to convert user enter string to safe string
2. How to get back user enter value form the converted string

Comment: Writing a constant as PHP code into a file is maybe not the best storage method to begin with...?!

Comment: The problem with this example is that you have `\t` which is the `tab` special character. It will be the same with `\r`, `\n` etc. So, try with `addcslashes` instead of `addslashes`, i.e. `addcslashes($str, "\t\r\n")`

Answer (score 0):

use [addslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php)

```
define ( 'TEXT_VAL', addslashes(your_val) );
```

Comment: yes i tried that how can i get back user enter value form the `TEXT_VAL` i tried addslashes() and stripslashes() functions thx

Answer (score 0):

I've tested [stripslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php)/[addslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) works OK

I've converted the outputstring as base64 to simulate user input. Base64 text is unescaped.

```
 $val = base64_decode('Y29tJ24iIHRlY1x0');
 echo "USERINPUT: ".$val.'<br>';
 define ( 'TEXT_VAL', addslashes($val) );

 echo "ESCAPED: ".TEXT_VAL.'<BR>';
 echo "STRIPPED: ".stripslashes(TEXT_VAL);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
USERINPUT: com'n" tec\t
ESCAPED: com\'n\" tec\\t
STRIPPED: com'n" tec\t
```

Answer (score 0):

use `addslashes` and `stripslashes`
For example
`addslashes(your string)` while saving and `strip_slashes(the result)` while displaying

Comment: This is problem when user enter `"`

Answer (score 0):

Just use serialize / unserialize.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

Answer (score 0):

```
sprintf("<?php define('TEXT_VAL', %s);", var_export($userText, true))
```

[`var_export`](http://php.net/var_export) makes sure you get the result as valid PHP code.

I'd still maintain that storing a value as a constant definition is not exactly the best way.